# Query locations between 2 GeoPoints

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

With [GeoFirestore](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android) I can query a location (lat/lon) to see if any locations in my collection/database are within a certain radius:

```
val collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("locations")
val geoFirestore = GeoFirestore(collectionRef)

val location1 = GeoPoint(37.7832, -122.4056)
val location2 = GeoPoint(37.3832, -121.4056)
val geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(location1, 0.6)
```

However, I want to query for a 3rd location *between* `location1` and `location2`.

For example, consider `location1` is Melbourne Central and `location2` is Mantra on the Park - can I query locations within the rectangle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GeoFirestore starts off by querying the documents based on a GeoHash. This leads to a roughly rectangular shape, which GeoFirestore then in-memory reduces to the requested range by [checking the actual distance of each document from the center](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/blob/34b935c534c583520a706c3388c57962122846bf/geofirestore/src/main/java/org/imperiumlabs/geofirestore/GeoQuery.java#L98).

While returning all documents in the rectangular shape isn't supported by the GeoFirestore out of the box, it should be fairly easy to modify the library to not do the distance filtering.